# Converts to be treated as if they were born Jewish

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, conversion-to-judaism

There is a scripture in the Tanakh where G-d clearly says a convert to Judaism is to be treated,as if he were born a Jew. I've seen it but can't seem to find it. Perhaps one more knowledgeable then I would know.  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Don Solins, and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including [our 214 other questions about converts and conversion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerut-conversion?sort=votes). Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including up- and down-voting others' posts.

Comment: Welcome! While there are verses that discuss the need to treat a convert as a native, there are some *very specific* circumstances in which they are treated differently. For one, there is a discussion as to whether they make the same declaration over *bikkurim* brought to the temple, since they cannot state that their forefathers were commanded (a reference to the *Avos*). Neither a female convert nor a child of two converts marry a Cohen, due to certain restrictions upon the Cohen.

Answer (score 12):

Does [Vayikro (Leviticus) 19:34](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#v=34) suit?

> כְּאֶזְרָח מִכֶּם יִהְיֶה לָכֶם הַגֵּר | הַגָּר אִתְּכֶם וְאָהַבְתָּ
>   לוֹ כָּמוֹךָ כִּי גֵרִים הֱיִיתֶם בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם אֲנִי יְקוָֹק
>   אֱלֹקיכֶם
>
> The stranger who sojourns with you shall be as a native from among
>   you, and you shall love him as yourself; for you were strangers in the
>   land of Egypt. I am the L-rd, your G-d.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that this does not (and cannot) say what the OP sought, as converts do have some different rules and restrictions.

Answer (score 8):

There are actually several places in the Pentateuch where this idea is mentioned, e.g.:

**Exodus 12:49**

> תּוֹרָה אַחַת יִהְיֶה לָאֶזְרָח וְלַגֵּר הַגָּר בְּתוֹכְכֶם - One law shall be to him
>   that is native, and unto the sojourner that sojourneth among you.

**Leviticus 19:34**

> כְּאֶזְרָח מִכֶּם יִהְיֶה לָכֶם הַגֵּר הַגָּר אִתְּכֶם
>   וְאָהַבְתָּ לוֹ כָּמוֹך כִּי גֵרִים הֱיִיתֶם בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם
>   אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹקיכֶם - The stranger that sojourneth with you
>   shall be unto you as the home-born among you, and thou shalt love him
>   as thyself; for ye were strangers in the land of Egypt. I am the L-RD
>   your G-d.

**Leviticus 24:22**

> מִשְׁפַּט אֶחָד יִהְיֶה לָכֶם כַּגֵּר כָּאֶזְרָח יִהְיֶה כִּי אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹקיכֶם - "Ye shall have one manner of law, as well for the stranger, as for the home-born; for I am the L-RD your G-d.'

**Numbers 15:15-16**

> 'הַקָּהָל חֻקָּה אַחַת לָכֶם וְלַגֵּר הַגָּר חֻקַּת עוֹלָם לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם כָּכֶם כַּגֵּר יִהְיֶה לִפְנֵי ה'. תּוֹרָה אַחַת וּמִשְׁפָּט אֶחָד יִהְיֶה לָכֶם וְלַגֵּר הַגָּר אִתְּכֶם - As for the congregation, there shall be one statute both for you, and for the stranger that sojourneth with you, a statute for ever throughout your generations; as ye are, so shall the stranger be before the L-RD.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that this does not (and cannot) say what the OP sought, as converts do have some different rules and restrictions.